# Use forwarded arguments in templated function to execute function with default parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction, default-arguments

I have a templated function `auto Run(Func f, Args&&... args)` which accaptes variadig arguments and a function to execute.

If the function I want to execute has default arguments set, I cannot use this function for my `Run` function whithout specifying every argument on its own. See the example below:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto Run(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int Int(int a, int b = 2){ return a + b; }

int main()
{
    Run(Int, 3, 2); // does compile, because every parameter is set
    Run(Int, 3); // does not compile
}
```

Is there a way that I could achieve both without changing how I call the function? I want to change the templated function only if possible

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution (starting from C++14) is wrap the `Int()` function in a generic lambda

```
 Run([](auto && ... as)
      { return Int(std::forward<decltype(as)>(as)...); }, 3, 2);
 Run([](auto && ... as)
      { return Int(std::forward<decltype(as)>(as)...); }, 3);
```

This way the compiler directly manage the call of the `Int()` function, maintain the knowledge of a default value for the second argument and use it.

The problem is that an argument default value isn't part of the signature of the functions, so the following functions

```
int Int_0 (int a, int b){ return a + b; }
int Int_1 (int a, int b = 2){ return a + b; }
int Int_2 (int a = 1, int b = 2){ return a + b; }
```

are function with the same signature and, so, are of the same type (`int(int, int)`).

If you pass `Int_2()` to a function accepting a `int(int, int)`, or a template parameter that is deduced as `int(int, int)` (as in your `Run()` case), the default values are loose.

Comment: Forget to mention that if possible I do't want to change how I can call this function...

Comment: @RoQuOTriX - I don't think it's possible, directly passing `Int()` as argument of a function. Answer improved to explain why.

Comment: Is there a different way I could pass the function? You mention directly passing? Is there an indirect way?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX - One indirect way is the one in my answer: wrapping the call of `Int()` inside a lambda function and pass the lambda function.